# Obtaining angular velocity of a general orbit

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, potential-energy

Provided you are given a effective potential function i.e. $$ V_{eff}=\dfrac{J^2}{2ml^2sin^2(\theta)} + mgl(1-cos(\theta))$$

how do you obtain the angular velocity for different types of orbits; i.e. circular orbit and the elliptical orbit? I don't need an answer for the potential above. I am interested in the solution for a general potential, I have tried looking at the Morin's Classical mechanics and some other webpages, but I could not find a comprehensive answer to this question.

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you looking for the instantaneous angular velocity, or the mean motion (time to complete one orbit)?